# deploying on local host redirecting to incorrect URL

Tags: asp.net, deployment, iis-7, web-deployment

I have a VS 2010 application that I migrated from VS 2003. 
It runs fine when run

```
http//localhost:51143/default.aspx
```

To deploy on the local host, I went to `Project->Properties->Web ->use Local IIS Web Server` and specified the Project URL as
     `http//localhost/TOrders>` and then Clicked '`Create Virtual Directory`'.

I then opened IIS7 manager and checked that the vitual directory was created.

However, when I run the application, it starts loading

```
http//localhost/TOrders/default.aspx
```

but then redirects to the intranet site and loads

```
http//mytsystem/default.aspx
```

instead.

I have tried in vain to fix the issue.